# Is this a valid way to show $\mathrm{Ind}_K^G W \cong \mathrm{Ind}_H^G \mathrm{Ind}_K^H W$? Stuck on a bit of the method

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I want to show for $K \leq H \leq G$ groups, $W$ a representation of $K$, that $\mathrm{Ind}_K^G W \cong \mathrm{Ind}_H^G \mathrm{Ind}_K^H W$.

If we write $V = \mathrm{Ind}_K^G W$, $V' = \mathrm{Ind}_K^H W$, then

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Ind}_H^G V' &= \bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} \sigma \cdot V' \\
&= \bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} \sigma \left(\bigoplus_{\tau \in H/K} \tau\cdot V \right) \\
&= \bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} \bigoplus_{\tau \in H/K} \sigma \cdot (\tau \cdot V).
\end{aligned}$$

I then want to say that each $\upsilon \in G/K$, we would have that $\upsilon \cdot V = \sigma \cdot (\tau \cdot V)$ for precisely one pair $(\sigma, \tau) \in G/H \times H/K$. Let's label this part $(\ast)$.

Then the map $\phi(\sigma, \tau) = \upsilon$ would be a bijection, and applying the map gives that

$$\mathrm{Ind}_H^G V' \cong \bigoplus_{\upsilon \in G/K} \upsilon \cdot V = \mathrm{Ind}_K^G W,$$

giving the result.

The bit I'm a little stuck on formalising is $(\ast)$. How do I know that this is the case, i.e. if $\sigma, \sigma' \in G/H$, $\tau, \tau' \in H/K$, then $\sigma \cdot (\tau \cdot V) = \sigma' \cdot (\tau' \cdot V) \iff \sigma = \sigma', \tau = \tau'$? This seems like it should be easy but I'm just missing something. I've tried giving explicit coset representations of $G/H$ and trying to construct an explicit bijection $\phi$ from this, but I'm struggling to show it's either injective or surjective for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\pi',V')$ be a representation of $H$. Pick a representative $S\subset G$ of $G/H$. Then $\mathrm{Ind}_H^GV'=\bigoplus_{\sigma\in S}\sigma V'$, where $g\in G$ acts as: for $\sigma\in S$, there exists a unique $\sigma'\in S$ and $h\in H$ such that $g\sigma=\sigma'h$. Then $\pi'(g)\cdot\sigma v=\sigma'\cdot \pi'(h)v$ for $\sigma\in S$ and $v\in V'$. One may check that this representation does not depend on the choice of representatives $S\subset G$.

Thus, take representatives $S\subset G$ of $G/H$ and $T\subset H$ of $H/K$. Then:
$$\mathrm{Ind}_H^G\mathrm{Ind}_K^HV=\bigoplus_{\sigma\in S}\bigoplus_{\tau\in T}\sigma\tau V=\bigoplus_{\alpha\in ST}\alpha V,$$
where $ST:=\{\sigma\tau:\sigma\in S,\tau\in H\}\subset G$ is a set of representatives for $G/K$.

Thus we have identified $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G\mathrm{Ind}_K^HV$ and $\mathrm{Ind}_K^GV$ as vector spaces. Let us track the $G$-action:

For $\sigma\in S$ and $\tau\in T$, for $v\in V$ and $g\in G$, we hope to compare the action of $g$ on $\sigma\tau v$. There is a unique $\sigma'\in T$ and $h\in H$ such that $g\sigma=\sigma'h$. There is a unique $\tau'\in T$ and $k\in K$ such that $h\tau=\tau'k$. Thus:
$$g\sigma\tau=\sigma'h\tau=\sigma'\tau'k.$$
The action of $g\in G$ on $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G\mathrm{Ind}_K^HV$ as $\sigma\tau v\mapsto \sigma'(h\cdot \tau v)=\sigma'\tau'kv$, while the action on $\mathrm{Ind}_K^GV$ as $\sigma\tau v\mapsto \sigma'\tau' kv$.